# PHP date_diff with if statement doesn't work properly

Tags: php, date, date-difference

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two different hours. Everything work fine! I create a function that return me the H:i:s

```
function dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 , $differenceFormat = '%r%a' ) {
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    $interval->format('%r%a');

    return $interval->format('%r%H:%i:%s');;
}

print dateDifference(date('H:i:s'), $orariof); ///$orariof is any time
```

This is the result: https://i.postimg.cc/0565G9c3/Immagine-2022-10-31-165134.png

But if I try to add the following if statement, the condition becomes true for the right options, except for one. If anyone could help me understand why the condition become true for the exception, I really appreciate it!

The function:

```
if(dateDifference(date('H:i:s'), $orariof)>date('H:i:s', strtotime('00:30:00'))){
  print dateDifference(date('H:i:s'), $orariof);
}
```

And the result: https://i.postimg.cc/y830wq1r/Immagine-2022-10-31-165104.png

The if statement print a time difference which shouldn't be printed because the difference is only 9 minutes

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you are trying to show us in the images. It would be best if you edited your question and include the results directly instead of as an image.

Comment: The if statement print a time difference which shouldn't be printed because the difference is only 9 minutes

Comment: The function doesn't actually do anything with the `$minutes` variable, should it?

Comment: The `$minutes` variable doesn't do anything, I'll remove it now

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I do not see any input data ?

Comment: You are returning the result of [`DateTime::format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) which is a string, and then are trying to perform string comparison logic on this which could be very fragile. You are also  return both a full date and time using `r`, as well as the time in hours, minutes and seconds. Lastly, you are using `%` syntax which isn't used in formatting of dates and instead brought over literally: https://3v4l.org/9JXKc